# HP ChromeBook 14 N Videa tegra k1

Tags: hp, chromebook

I have ordered a HP chrome book 14 with the tegra k1 processor. Am I able to run Ubuntu Linux on this processor? I had a look at other threads and could not find the answer I was looking for. I know it runs on the Intel haswell processors but I'm unsure of the architechure of the tegra chip. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need Ubuntu 14.04 LTS for [ARM-32](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-armhf/current/images/generic/netboot/) or for [ARM-64](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-arm64/current/images/generic/netboot/) depending on HP's choice of processor for the notebook. (Ask HP, as I can't find that on their website and report back in the comments if it's 64 bit or 32 bit)

Comment: Hey thanks for the response. I'm unsure of the architechure, regardless, how does the software run on an arm processor? Also would the installation be done through the traditional chrubuntu or crouton method? Thanks in advance

Comment: :D Again, *that depends on HP*: if you get a developer ROM, you can use ChrUbuntu, otherwise you're stuck with crouton

Comment: Okay, the installation method, is crouton the same for an arm processor? Also what about hardware support?

Comment: I don't understand the questions... Can you elaborate?

Comment: Im asking about the installation process, i cant find any info for an arm processor.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed you posted links in the original answer, thanks for the help :)

Comment: Don't thank me, just accept my answer as valid and vote it up once you have enough reputation...  (that's worth  more then a "thank you" note in the comments as my reputation will go up...)  ;-)

Comment: Keeping a long story short. =)

Answer (score 1):

Solution is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/835755/install-ubuntu-arm-lts-on-a-hp-chromebook-14-g3-tegra-k1-nyan-blaze/)

I have the same hardware as you and full GPU acceleration (60fps on www.fishgl.com)

If you follow the instructions, and install to a fast 32GB+ USB 3.0 pen drive (using the USB 3.0 port next to HDMI), you'll have Trusty Tahr and everything working.

The Tegra K1 GPU acceleration only works with 14.04.  Do not attempt to upgrade to 16.04 as other things will also break.

You can make regular compressed backups of the ChrUbuntu disk image and restore if necessary.  After restoring, you need to sign the kernel image from within the Chrome OS shell.

[Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-NLleDS4IRqR0gtQzJFdGpseFk) are the scripts I currently use, for install, backup and signing.

Best Wishes, Spearthistle.

Comment: If the linked question answers this one, flag this question as a duplicate of the other.  (Also, please refrain from using shortened links, you can use full links without issue here normally.)

Comment: Done and noted.  Don't we say "Hi" anymore :)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest to wait before buying an HP14 Tegra K1 if you only want to use it with chrubuntu/crouton (ubuntu based) since it doesn't work yet.
I tried to install chrubuntu through this script : [chrubuntu-tegra][Chrubuntu-Tegra] https://github.com/VCTLabs/chrubuntu-tegra
But it didn't work, failing on rsyslog install. Tried many other scripts but this one seems to be the best choice.
I also tried to duplicate an existing SD i had for an acer CB5-311-T8BT (also tegra K1, working fine), it looked better at first but the boot process ended up with a fatal error.
At this point, only Crouton seems to work and with the well known "inverted colors" bug. Seems to be a fix for that one.