# Install Ubuntu ARM LTS on a HP Chromebook 14 G3 (Tegra K1, nyan_blaze)

Tags: chromebook, arm, crouton

As described above with a hardware accelerated Gnome, Unity or XFCE desktop?
I'm currently limping on with crouton for the time being.

Ideally:

1. A backed up Chromebook OS replaced.
2. OR an external SD Card / fast USB 3.0 drive booted into at startup.

Best Wishes, Spearthistle.

Comment: Currently, crouton is the only way to get Ubuntu installed on a Chromebook. I'm currently using this setup to type this answer, what issues are you having with it?

Comment: Lack of hardware acceleration.

Comment: This guy got a similar Tegra K1 chromebook to be hardware accelerated with Fedora ARM 23.  I tried following the instructions posted but encountered problems as I'm not au fait with the technicalities.
https://kushaldas.in/posts/fedora-23-on-tegra-k1-chromebook.html

Comment: I'll have to look at that. This answer could benefit you and I both :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Happy days @OwenHines.

There's a ChrUbuntu thread on Reddit that has a modified ChrUbuntu script compatible with the HP Chromebook 14 G3 Tegra K1 nyan_blaze ARM architecture (I cannot post the original link here because I don't have at least 10 reputation points for 2 links).

The script had a couple of minor bugs, which I've fixed, available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-NLleDS4IRqel9XWGhZSDFTZkk?usp=sharing), and I also
added 'username', 'password' and 'hostname' variables to the top of the
script so that you don't have to change these details after installation.

If you read the script, it says that you have to run (slightly elaborated):
    `sudo parted --script /dev/<device_id> "mktable gpt"` where `<device_id>` is either `sd[a|b|c|d] (usb stick)` or `mmcblk1 (sd card)`

first, to create an empty gpt partition table (because Chrome OS shell no longer has the parted command).

After that execute `sudo bash chrubuntu-tegra-HP-Chromebook-14-Tegra-K1.sh default latest /dev/<device_id>` which will install **Trusty Tahr 14.04.5 LTS** and the **Unity Desktop**

I installed to a fast 32GB+ USB 3.0 pen drive and performance is good.

After the script finishes press enter to reboot and then Ctrl-U when on
the Chromebook Boot Screen.

I tested various webgl benchmarks.  [www.fishgl.com](http://www.fishgl.com) ran at 60fps

Don't upgrade to 16.04 because lots of things break and Tegra K1 GPU acceleration is only supported by this 14.04 install.

The other scripts, "backup" and "sign" are for compressed backups and for restoration.  You have to sign the restored kernel whilst in the Chrome OS shell.

Best Wishes, @spearthistle.

Comment: the link to your script no longer works. Would you please be able to post it  inline here within your answer or if it's too large to a gist on Github?